# Datatables with laravel how to render hasMany relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, datatables

i have the following response from my controller

```
[
  {
     "id": 1,
     "place_id": 1,
     "name": "Test",
     "type": 5,
     "created_at": "2018-06-04 15:29:02",
     "updated_at": "2018-06-04 15:29:02",
     "time": [
         {
            "id": 1,
            "stadium_id": 1,
            "day": "Saturday",
            "from_hour": 7,
            "to_hour": 12,
            "created_at": "2018-06-04 15:29:42",
            "updated_at": "2018-06-04 15:29:42"
         },
         {
            "id": 2,
            "stadium_id": 1,
            "day": "Sunday",
            "from_hour": 7,
            "to_hour": 12,
            "created_at": "2018-06-04 15:54:03",
            "updated_at": "2018-06-04 15:54:03"
         }
    ]
  }
]
```

i want to access the day attribute in each time object

i tried the code below but of course it just loads the first result
is there a solution

```
columns: [
         { data: 'name' },
         { data: 'type' },
         { data: 'time.0.day' },
         { data: 'time.0.from_hour' },
         { data: 'time.0.to_hour' },


    ],
```

Comment: what do you mean by access?

Comment: render it as a row in my view

Comment: How do you create the response?

Comment: public function getType($id)
    {
        $st = \App\Stadiums::where('type', $id)->get();
        $st->load('time');
        return response()->json($st,200);
    }

Comment: You want them to be in different rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually access `time` array by using the [`render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) property:

```
 columns: [{
      data: 'name'
    },
    {
      data: 'type'
    },
    {
      data: 'time',
      render: function(data, type, row) {
        var txt = '';
        data.forEach(function(item) {
          if (txt.length > 0) {
            txt += '</br> '
          }
          txt += item.day;
        });
        return txt;
      }
    },
   ...
```

This would just add a line break for every objects in `time`. Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mattmorz/smn18q5h/) for you to examine.